# Enabling Loop Time of Imported Animation in Unity using Script

Tags: c#, loops, unity-game-engine, animation, time

While we can simply edit "Loop Time" parameter of the imported animation files using the Inspector in Unity, when there are many animation files this process can be tiresome. Is there an easy way of setting animation parameters such as "Loop Time" or "Bake Rotation into Pose" for multiple animation files in script?

Choosing mutliple animation files and editing them in the Inspector is not possible as each file contains a different animation and Unity does not allow them to be edited simultaneously.

Answer (score 0):

For this problem, we can use the following editor-specific code to set the needed properties of the imported animation:

```
foreach (AnimationClip clip in anim.runtimeAnimatorController.animationClips)
{
    AnimationClipSettings settings = AnimationUtility.GetAnimationClipSettings(clip);
    if (settings.loopTime == false)
    {
        settings.loopTime = true;
        settings.keepOriginalOrientation = true;
        settings.keepOriginalPositionXZ = true;
        settings.keepOriginalPositionY = true;
        settings.loopBlend = true;
        settings.loopBlendOrientation = true;
        settings.loopBlendPositionXZ = true;
        settings.loopBlendPositionY = true;
        AnimationUtility.SetAnimationClipSettings(clip, settings);
    }
}

foreach (AnimationClip ac in anim.runtimeAnimatorController.animationClips)
{
    ac.wrapMode = WrapMode.Loop;
}
```

Note that calling it once will set the properties, and then you can exclude this code (which only runs in Editor due to AnimationUtility) in your build.